# playframework webdrive 0.2

Tags: playframework, webdriver

I use PlayFramework and webdrive 2.0 play-module for testing with webdriver. Everything was fine until I update firefox in my Ubuntu. After this my tests open empty firefox-browser and nothing happens.

I tried to use chrome browser for tests like was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166222/using-chrome-driver-with-webdrive-and-selenium-2-4). But there is the another problem, it starts chrome first time, but after it even can not lunch the browser (until reboot the system) - no any error in log.

In fact I prefer to use firefox for testing... but it seem it is a bunch of problems with that, there is a dependencies of current installed browser in the system. Not nice..

Could someone suggest something?

P.S.
 For FireFox I got this exception:

```
Unable to connect to host localhost on port 7055 after 45000 ms
```

I guess, I need update webdriver version... but webdrive play-module uses it's own version in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: just updated the dependencies in the webdrive module to use latest webdriver. Like this:

```
self: play -> webdrive 0.2

require:
    - play
    - org.seleniumhq.selenium -> selenium-java 2.13.0
```